# Import CSV into polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, csv, import

I have commune level map in shapefile and CSV.

Originally, I have shapefile, exported it to CSV, then to STATA for data manipulation.  Then I have exported it as CSV to import to QGIS as polygon.

I wanted to find WKT in the CSV file, but it is not straight-forward as x and y coordinates as in point data.

Please help me import the CSV into QGIS as polygon.

https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/dataset/c70a9555-2918-4455-a144-9716a96fc3da/resource/939608e9-4b1f-404b-8174-f0d6be609ecb/download/shp_census_2008.zip
https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/dataset/c70a9555-2918-4455-a144-9716a96fc3da/resource/4b99aba0-ce2d-4790-8d74-8fb30f83f5b7/download/csv_census_2008.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the WKT. You have shapfiles that contain a code like COMM_CODE for communes. I assume it's the same code that can be found in your csv files as well. So just join these files: associate the csv data to the polygons of your shapefile.

Load all data, shapefiles and csv data to QGIS. Rightclick on your shapefile, let's say on the commune polygon layer (1 on the screenshot below). Select the Joins tab (2) and add a join with the green + (3). Select the associated csv file and set the common field, in this example COMM_CODE (4). Confirm with OK (5).

The data from the csv are now added as attribute to your shapefile, you can use it as common attributes.

[image]